# UPDATE FROM is not working with multiple update of same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have @Products and @TempProducts tables. I want to Update @Products from @TempProducts.

My code:

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE(
  Id INT, 
  Name NVARCHAR(255), 
  Description NVARCHAR(255));

DECLARE @TempProducts TABLE(
  RowNumber int, 
  Id INT, 
  Name NVARCHAR(255), 
  Description NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO @Products(Id,Name,Description) VALUES(1,'Name1','Desc1');

INSERT INTO @TempProducts(RowNumber,Id,Name,Description)
  VALUES(1,1,'NewName1',NULL);
INSERT INTO @TempProducts(RowNumber,Id,Name,Description)
  VALUES(2,1,NULL,'NewDesc1');
INSERT INTO @TempProducts(RowNumber,Id,Name,Description)
  VALUES(3,1,NULL,'NewDesc2');
INSERT INTO @TempProducts(RowNumber,Id,Name,Description)
  VALUES(4,1,'NewName2',NULL);

WITH TP AS
(
    SELECT TOP (100000) RowNumber,Id,Name,DESCRIPTION 
    FROM @TempProducts 
    ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
)
UPDATE  P
   SET  Name = ISNULL(TP.Name,P.Name),
        Description = ISNULL(TP.Description,P.Description)
FROM    @Products P
        INNER JOIN TP
            ON P.Id = TP.Id

SELECT * FROM @Products
```

Expected:

```
Id   Name       Description
---------------------------
1    NewName2   NewDesc2
```

But getting:

```
Id   Name       Description
---------------------------
1    NewName1   NewDesc1
```

Note that I am ordering by ORDER BY RowNumber means Update RowNumber1 first then second and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria
>   for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are
>   undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not
>   specified in such a way that only one value is available for each
>   column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is
>   not deterministic.

I would do it like this:

```
UPDATE P SET   Name = ISNULL(ca1.Name, P.Name), Description = ISNULL(ca2.Description, P.Description)
FROM @Products P
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM @TempProducts WHERE ID = p.ID AND Name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RowNumber DESC) ca1
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Description FROM @TempProducts WHERE ID = p.ID AND Description IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RowNumber DESC) ca2
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't SQL Update the first record record and then second and so on.

Comment: What you quoted contradicts your answer. The quote says "this is undefined" and you say "just use DESC".

Comment: @usr, it is incorrect update, results are undefined. I don't know the internals but in this particular scenario it just updates with first values. May be it depends on situation, parallelism and other facts, I don't know, but the fact that it worked for me. But of course I wouldn't do it like this myself.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what undefined means and at the same time seem to understand it. Confusing. Undefined means that it can work correctly, or not. "Worked for me" might be true but it might not work for anyone else or for all time.

Comment: @usr right it is working for the above example but not for my real table

Comment: @user960567, I have updated answer with correct solution

Comment: I have more than 10 columns in my real table. Should I add more than 10 joins? :)

Comment: @user960567, with this solution the answer is YES. Wait for better answer.

Comment: Its not working. Just put 1 before last name and desc

Comment: @user960567, I have already changed to version with  `outer apply`. It should work.

Comment: Check mine and see which is better

Comment: Tried your it still not working. However my last UPDATE was working.

Comment: @user960567, your edits will still be undefined. See version with OUTER APPLY where you are guaranteed to pick just 1 value.

Comment: Right your version is working with slight modification. Thanks. I am updating your answer you can check.

Comment: See the last edit, it is more correct. Don't update others answers. Update your question instead

Comment: Sorry. Will not do again.

Comment: Don't update my answer :) I am loosing my own edits. Edit your own answer. I will update the answer, because you don't need the CTE at all

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. What if all rows of Temp table is NULL. I need to take old Value.

Comment: @user960567, added ISNULL functions

Comment: Why you removed the JOIN. It checking all rows instead of joined ones. See question.

Comment: Outer apply is similar to left join in this situation and is more correct.

Comment: But if I have multiple rows in Products table it checks all rows of TempProducts instead of that specific row to grab Name,Desc,etc

Comment: I can not really understand what you are talking about. For every row in Products table the query will find first occurence of non null column Name and update it with that value, if all columns in temp are nulls then you update products table with the name from products table. the same is true for Description

Comment: Assume that we have 2 rows in Products table with Id=1 and Id=2 and there are rows of TempProducts for Id=1 and Id=2. All the changes will apply on both rows of Products. Means if TempTable include Id=2,Name=abc as last row. Then it also update this Name with Id=1

Comment: @user960567, no this is not true. Look how I filter `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM @TempProducts WHERE ID = p.ID AND Name IS NOT NULL` . I am filtering values from temp by `ID = p.ID`.

Comment: Ok I forget this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple matches, then SQL Server does not specify which gets updated.  If you want the last (or first) value updated, then use window functions to find it:

```
WITH TP AS (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARRTITION BY ID ORDER BY RowNumber DESC) as seqnum
    FROM (SELECT TOP (100000) tp.*
          FROM @TempProducts ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
         ) t
)
UPDATE  P
   SET  Name = ISNULL(TP.Name,P.Name),
        Description = ISNULL(TP.Description,P.Description)
FROM    @Products P INNER JOIN
        TP
        ON P.Id = TP.Id AND seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just want the last not null-able value of Name and Description should win. May be last not null-able value of Name is on Row=4 of  TempProducts and last not null-able value of Name is on Row=3 of  TempProducts of the same product.